# Why does my if statement keep my integer I at 2

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to figure out why my if statement creates an endless loop.

```
var gname = "Glenn"
var aNames = 
    [
    "Brian",
    "John",
    "Frank",
    "George",
    "Melissa",
    "Julie"
    ]

var i = 0

do {
    console.log("Hello " + aNames[i]);
    console.log("i = " + i)
    if (i = 1){ console.log("Failed")}
    i=i+1;
} 
while (i < 6)
```

Comment: `=` for assignment, `==` or `===` for comparison.

Comment: Thank you. Duh.  I'm used to VB .net.    But I do remember this now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line:

```
if (i = 1){ console.log("Failed")}
```

The `=` operator above sets `1` to the `i` variable. You should compare the values using the `===` operator, like this:

```
if (i === 1){ console.log("Failed")}
```